# Access objects in custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I use custom UITableViewCells with button, label and a progress view in each cell.

I set the tag of each object in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so each object has the same tag which also is the row of the cell in the tableview.

The problem is, how am I suppose to access the progress view object and show some progress when the button is pressed in a cell? How would I properly access this objects in a method that doesn't have a `NSIndexPath` parameter?

Thanks

UITableViewCell setup:

```
class SongsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {    
    @IBOutlet weak var lblSongTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnPlayPause: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressCell:UIProgressView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
}
```

DetailsViewController with UITableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SongTitleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SongsTableViewCell
        let songDic : NSDictionary = arrSongs.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSDictionary

        cell.lblSongTitle.text = songDic.objectForKey("SongTitle") as? String
        cell.btnPlayPause.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.progressCell.tag = indexPath.row
}
```

Action for the Button in the cell:

```
 @IBAction func cellSongClicked (sender : AnyObject ){

       // Need to access the progress view here....

      var btnCurrentPressed = sender as UIButton
      var cell = self.tableView.viewWithTag(btnCurrentPressed.tag)
      var progressInCell : UIProgressView!
}
```

I want when I click the button `btnPlayPause` to access the progressCell and show some processing.

Comment: Can you post some code to make it more clear what you're doing? You can pass the progress view object into the method.

Comment: @Chris I added the codes

Answer (score 0):

**How would I properly access this objects in a method that doesn't have a NSIndexPath parameter?**

Create a integer variable in `@interface` class and assign  in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method like following

Declare a variable in a class:

```
  int someInteger;
```

After in the following method you have to assign like this.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

        someInteger = indexPath.row;
    }
```

And you can access `someInteger` in some other methods.

Comment: the code is not in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` its in the cellSongClicked function